# How do I structure this medium sized flask application?

Tags: authentication, flask, authorization, flask-security

Using the FLASK framework in Python, my application needs to:

1. register and log in users (with either a sqlite or postgres database)
2. access a specific google spreadsheet that the logged in user owns and output that data in a json format.
   **I am required to have my own authorization & authentication system**

I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to even structure the application - what directories and sub-directories should I have?

I have done A LOT of playing around (about 1 months worth). I am using a virtual environment but don't know how to test my code well either. In general, my code runs but I have no idea how they work together really.** I am completely new to flask.**

**Structuring the app**:

|app

|----run.py

|----config.py

|----database

|---------database.db

|----app

|---------views.py

|---------models.py

|---------forms.py

|---------extensions.py

|----templates

|---------....

|----static

|--------....

**Authorization / Authentication**: 
*I have looked at Flask-Login, Flask-Auth, Flask-Security. I understand the general idea but do not know how to securely implement a complete authorization & authentication system.*

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(config)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

def create_app():   
    db.init_app()
    db.app = app
    db.create_all()
    return app

@app.route('/')
def index():
     #needs to render the homepage template

@app.route('/signup', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = SignupForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('signup.html', form=form)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            if User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first():
                return "email exists"
            else:
                newuser = User(form.email.data, form.password.data)
                db.session.add(newuser)
                db.session.commit()
                login_user(newuser)

            return "New User created"
    else:
        return "form didn't validate"

    return "Signup"

@app.route('/login', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = SignupForm()

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('login.html', form=form)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
            if user:
                if user.password == form.password.data:
                    login_user(user)
                    return "you are logged in"
                else:
                    return "wrong password"
            else:
                return "user doesnt exist"
        else:
            return "form did not validate"

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(email):
    return User.query.filter_by(email = email).first()

@app.route('/protected')
@login_required
def protected():
    return "protected area for logged in users only"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.create_app()
    app.run(port=5000, host='localhost')`
```

---

```
from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, UserMixin, RoleMixin, login_required
import os

# Create app
app = Flask(__name__)
#app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '' 
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////'
app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_HASH'] = 'sha512_crypt'
app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT'] = str(os.urandom(24))
# Create database connection object
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Define models
roles_users = db.Table('roles_users',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id')))

class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True) 
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True) 
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True) 
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,  backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))


user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore)

# Create a user to test with
@app.before_first_request 
def create_user():
    db.create_all()
    user_datastore.create_user(email='', password='')
    db.session.commit()

@app.route('/') 
@login_required 
def home():
    #password = encrypt_password('mypass')
    #print verify_and_update_password('mypass', password)
    return "hello"

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

** I would really appreciate any guidance!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya'll, i figured it out & my app is LOOKING GOOD :)I am using blueprints & an application factory pattern.

```
APP
|_runserver.py
|_/app
|---__init__.py
|---config.py
|---extensions.py
|---forms.py
|---models.py
|---/login_dashboard #blueprint
|------__init__.py
|------views.py
|------/templates
|---------base.html
             .
             .
|------/static
|-----------/css
              .
              .
|-----------/js
              .
              .
|-----------/img
              .
              .
```

Answer (score 0):

**Project structure:**
If you're planning to build a larger Flask application, you should consider decomposing the functionality into Blueprints.
The official Flask documentation has a tutorial on how to structure larger applications:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/packages/

Also, take a look at the Hitchhiker's guide to organizing your project. It has some very good points: http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing/structure/

If you're designing an REST API consider using Flask-RESTful (which also works nicely with Blueprints)

Comment: thanks for the quick feedback! I've read through those docs, just having a hard time sorting out which views / routes I need and what not.

Comment: started looking into RESTful and it's great! thank you